# Probability question involving a lift

Tags: probability

I am stuck at the following probability problem. Will appreciate your help.

**An office block has five floors (ground, 1, 2, 3 and 4), all connected by a lift. When it goes up to any floor (except 4), the probability that after it has stopped it will continue to rise is 3/4. When it goes down to any floor (except the ground floor), the probability that after it has stopped it will continue to go down is 1/4. The lift stops at any floor it passes.**

**The lift is currently at the first floor having just descended. Calculate the probability of the following events:**

**a) its second stop is the third floor

b) its third stop is the fourth floor

c) its fourth stop is the first floor.**

For part (a), I did this: **P(first stop is the second floor)*P(second stop is the third floor) = (3/4)(3/4) = 9/16**

For part (b), I did this:

**P(first stop is the second floor)*P(second stop is the third floor)*P(third stop is the fourth floor) 
= (3/4)(3/4)(3/4) = 27/64**

Since the lift is going up and continuing to rise after it stopped at each floor from first floor, finding answers to part (a) and (b) was easy, even though it is unsure whether my logic is sensible or not. Somehow the answers for part (a) and (b) are correct according to the book. If my methods and answers are incorrect, let me know.

Now, I am really stuck at part (c). Not understanding how to solve the problem. How will the lift’s fourth stop be the first floor if the lift is continuing to rise from first floor and start descending from the fourth floor? Let me know where the mistake is.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: You need to enumerate the routes that work.  the elevator might go $0-1-0-1$, for example.  Or $2-3-2-1$, etc.  Easy to calculate the probability of each.

Comment: Note:  unless I am misreading, this process is not path dependent at all.  That is, if the elevator is on $1,2,3$ then the probability that it goes down next is $\frac 14$, regardless of what it did to get there.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: I thought the lift will go from 0-1-2-3-4 and 4-3-2-1-0 successively. I followed the pattern of the questions.

Comment: Why should it do that?  At any point, it might go up or down (with some probability).

Comment: Thanks. I will attempt solving part (c) from new perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following routes get you from the first floor to the first floor within $4$ moves:

- UUDD
- UDUD
- UDDU
- DUUD
- DUDU
- DDUU is impossible, since we cannot start by going down twice

Now, simply calculate the probability of each route, and then add up the results.

Comment: The general method is to split the problem into **disjoint** events, and then add up their probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the possible routes you provided and your suggestions.

Comment: @tantrik: You're welcome. Do you understand how to solve from this point?

Comment: I got **45/256**. The answer in the book is **29/128**. Don't know whether the book's answer is correct or not. I took P(U) = 3/4 and P(D) = 1/4. Then for each route the probability is 9/256 which I added together to get 45/256. Let me know where the mistake is.

Comment: I got the answer correct this time. I know where the mistake is.

Comment: @tantrik: Well, where is it then?

Comment: I did not consider that the probability of the lift to go from underground to the first floor is 1.